# Historical Data YouTube Reporting API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I am using the YouTube Reporting API, when the jobs were created it only generated reports for the past 30 days from the date of creation. What is the best way to go about gathering historical data past those 30 days to have a complete dataset?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation [YouTube Reporting API - Data Model](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports)

[image]

This api only returns data for the last 30 days.

My advice would be to run the report once a month and store your data on your own system.  YouTube analytics does not have any way of getting data more then thirty days old.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I suspected. You would think YouTube would have some option for content creators that started using their API years/months after they start their channel.